# How to convert multi-dimensional array into one-dimensional array in CLICKHOUSE

Tags: clickhouse

I have a multi-dimensional array, i want it to a one-dimensional array.
Here is an example

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]] => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

How to achieve it  with Clickhouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use function [arrayFlatten / flatten](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/array-functions/#arrayflatten):

```sql
SELECT arrayFlatten([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]])
/*
┌─arrayFlatten([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]])─┐
│ [1,2,3,4,5]                       │
└───────────────────────────────────┘
*/
```